# Does addition of clause change tense

Tags: grammatical-number, tenses

For example, which of the following sentences is correct:

Jack, and his partner Jill, **offer** a new perspective on child-rearing.

Jack, and his partner Jill, **offers** a new perspective on child-rearing.

Does the addition of the clause "and his partner Jill" change the tense of the verb "to offer"? Should I just leave out the commas for clarity?

Comment: In both cases, the _tense_ of the verb is the same. Its a simple present both times.

Comment: (1) it's not a clause; it's a noun phrase. Clauses have verbs and subjects. (2) tense has nothing to do with it. As @oerkelens points out, both are present tense. (3) conjunction of the noun phrase _his partner Jill_ with the noun phrase _Jack_ forms a conjoined noun phrase _Jack and his partner Jill_, which is **plural** (i.e, 1 + 1 = 2). (4) The verb _offers_, with a final /-z/, is a singular verb form. (5) The verb _offer_ is a plural verb form. (6) The verb form agrees with the subject in number. Got all that? OK. Next time don't use technical terms.

Answer (score 1):

Jack and Jill are offering a perspective together, so you would use the plural form of the verb. You would say, "Jack and his partner, Jill, offer a new perspective on child-rearing."

Note that the number of nouns doesn't dictate the tense. "Offer" and "offers" are both present tense. The number of nouns dictates the plurality. (See the comments by @oerkelens and @John Lawler for further information.)